# Is there a way to make a deployment to AWS EKS using boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-eks

I've reading through many documentations trying to figure out way to deploy objects to EKS using a python script or client. My objective is to be able then to trigger AWS Lambda that deploy objects to EKS.

Is there a possible way ?

Comment: Flux and argocd are some of the more popular choices for EKS deployment. What is the reasoning for wanting the deployment to be initiated by lambda?

Comment: Yes, you can use the Kubernetes Python SDK, https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/examples/deployment_create.py. I agree with @jordanm in that it might be better to use a solution like cdk8s, https://github.com/cdk8s-team/cdk8s-examples/tree/main/python/cdk8s-core, to generate manifests that are applied using a GitOps operator like Flux.